# Python list format from mysqldb

Tags: python, list, tuples, mysql-python

I'm trying to use a Class (adns-python) which is expecting a list in the format:

```
domain_names = ["google.com", "yahoo.com"]
```

This is working when I declare the list that way manually. However, I'm trying to use a list returned from mysql using python-mysqldb.

When I look at what is being returned from mysql using:

```
type(mysql_rows)
```

This also shows as a list, but when view the result:

```
print(mysql_rows)
```

I can see the list is in the format:

```
 [('google.com',), ('yahoo.com',)]
```

I've tried forcing the output to a list again using list(mysql_rows) which didn't work. I've tried parsing the text manually to make it look like the list using:

```
text_rows = "[" + ", ".join'"%s"' % i for i in mysql_rows = "]"
```

Which then shows as the correct format, but it is a string not a list so this doesn't work either.

This is my first few days learning python, so I'm sorry if this is an obvious/stupid question.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mysql returns a list of tuples.  Each tuple is a result row in your result set.  If you want a list of only the first "column" in the result, try this:

```
first_column = [x[0] for x in mysql_rows]
```

Answer (score 6):

The list is a list of tuples. A simple

```
lst = [x for x, in mysql_rows]
```

should be sufficient.

Comment: Your answer was totally correct too - I selected secretmike because he was a min sooner. Thank you as well.

Comment: @direct00: Fair enough :) Glad to help, have fun!